# Type 'String!' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Tags: ios, swift

how to resolve this in swift iOS 8.0 i.e `Type 'String!' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'`

here is my code

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace?) -> Bool
{
    return protectionSpace?.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
// Here I got this error near == sign
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge?)
{
    if challenge?.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
    {
        if challenge?.protectionSpace.host == "www.myhost.com"

// Here I got this error near == sign

        {
            let credentials = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge!.protectionSpace.serverTrust)
            challenge!.sender.useCredential(credentials, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
        }
    }

    challenge?.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
}
```

Comment: Are you running an old xcode6 beta?

Comment: @MikePollard yes I am

Comment: Upgrade to Xcode 6.0.1 and all will be well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem resolved by the public release of later versions of this software.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the comments about simply upgrading to the latest release for a solution. [It's a better practice to unwrap optionals with a nil check](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) before doing other comparisons. I would rewrite your code (albeit a bit more verbose than need be) as follows, which should also fix your issue in all versions:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace?) -> Bool
{
    if let authenticationMethod = protectionSpace?.authenticationMethod 
    {
        return authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
    }

    return false
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge?)
{
    if let authenticationMethod = challenge?.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
    {
        if authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
        {
            if challenge?.protectionSpace.host == "www.myhost.com"
            {
                let credentials = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge!.protectionSpace.serverTrust)
                challenge!.sender.useCredential(credentials, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
            }
        }
    }

    challenge?.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
}
```